# Codeigniter can't login into home admin

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the controller, when I click the login button, nothing happens. What I want is to load the success screen when user data is validated and show error messages when user data is not validated.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
        
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    function getlogin() {
        $user = $this->input->post('username');
        $pass = $this->input->post('password');
        $user = $this->auth->log_admin($user,$pass);
            if($user==true){
                $this->session->set_userdata($user);
                $data['hasil']=1;
                echo json_encode($data);
            }else{
                $data['hasil'] = 0;
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
    }

    function logout(){
        //helper_log("logout", "Logout");
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Login','refresh');
    }
}
```

Here the log_admin

```
function log_admin($user,$pass)
   {  
      $cek=$this->CI->db->where('admin_user',$user)
                        ->where('admin_password',md5($pass))
                        ->get('admin')
                        ->row();
      $row=count($cek);
      if ($row==1) {
         return $cek;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
```

Comment: show your `log_admin` function please.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score -1):

you can redirect the page from the controller, something like this.
after validating the user, it will redirect to your desired page.

```
function getlogin() {
        $user = $this->input->post('username');
        $pass = $this->input->post('password');
        $user = $this->auth->log_admin($user,$pass);
            if($user==true){
                $this->session->set_userdata($user);
                
                redirect('go to the next page');
            }else{
                
                $data['hasil'] = 0;
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think that this is "easier"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase , updated the answer, sorry for bad explanation, its my first time answering question